# Buttons resized after Migrating to Flex 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, button, migration, flex4.6

I am migrating an existing Flex application from 4.0 to 4.6. After the upgrade, the Button width is resized in my application and the edges are actually outside the panel component after upgrading to Flex 4.6. Any reasons why this is happening? I read that there are cosmetic changes that occur after upgrading to Flex 4.6, but that is about it.

In my application we have defined the spark Button as follows:

```
<s:Button xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
      creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)"
      height="25" styleName="dpransparentButton">
```

Is there an easy fix? Did I provide enough information to get the answer I am looking for right now?

I see these warnings in the output of the maven build:

> [WARNING] C:\Projects\trunk\daip-flex-domain\src\main\flex\GroupLocation.as:[12,18] No constructor function was specified for class GroupLocation.    public class GroupLocation extends GroupLocationBase {
>
> [WARNING] C:\Projects\trunk\daip-flex-domain\src\main\flex\LocationNotam.as:[12,18] No constructor function was specified for class LocationNotam.    public class LocationNotam extends LocationNotamBase {
>
> [WARNING] The swc 'C:\Projects\daip-library\trunk\daip-repository\com\adobe\flex\framework\framework\4.6.0.23201\framework-4.6.0.23201.swc' has style defaults and is in the library-path, which means dependencies will be linked in without the styles.  This can cause applications, which use the output swc, to have missing skins.  The swc should be put in the external-library-path.
>
> [WARNING] C:\Projects\daip\trunk\daip-flex-gui\src\main\flex\ui\user\views\UserManagementView.mxml:[331,-1] Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to "length".

Comment: So I migrated back to Flex 4.0 and the button size returned to normal. It is indeed a problem with the migration to Flex 4.6. Any ideas on how to keep Flex 4.6 and get my original button size back?

Answer (score 0):

The default padding changed, you can use paddingRight="0" paddingLeft="0" in your controls